# Insert data from table into another in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, insert

I try to insert data from one table into another table

table 1 (from where I select data )

**update**

```
   divid  divname
    --------------
    1      abc
    2      def
    4      xyz
    5       fgh
    6        ekg
    8        sdf
```

table2 (table from where I insert data into)

```
divdw_id   divid
```

**update:** 
i want data like this

```
divdw_id    divid
001          1
002          2
003          4
004          5
005          6
006          8
```

I try this this query for inserting data but this shows an error

```
insert into table2 
values (001, Divid)

select DivId 
from Oper_Db.dbo.table1
```

but this shows an error

> Invalid column name 'Divid'.

So how do I resolve this error?

**UPDATE:**

when i run only select statement query

```
insert into DivisionMap (divBI_Id, DiviOp_id)
 select RIGHT('000'+CAST(eindex as VARCHAR(3)),3),eindex from mydatabase.dbo.employee
```

then this shows like this

```
(No column name)    eindex
000                    0
022                   22
024                   24
025                   25
027                   27
028                   28
```

where as i want like this

```
(No column name)    eindex
000                    0
001                   22
002                  24
003                  25
004                   27
005                   28
```

Comment: The errormessage `Invalid column name 'Divid'.` clearly states the problem: Your column name is `divid` but your'e selecting `DivId` in your query which is difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing it wrong. You can only give 1 row at a time for values If you want to have the first column hardcoded values like 001 and the 2nd one with Table1.Divid then Try this :

```
insert into table2 (divdw_id,Divid)
 select '001',DivId from Oper_Db.dbo.table1
```

Or if 001 is a sequence No, then try this

```
insert into table2 (divdw_id,Divid)
 select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY DivId),DivId from Oper_Db.dbo.table1
```

if you need to prefix 0's to the divdw_id try this

```
insert into table2 (divdw_id,Divid)
 select RIGHT('000'+CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY DivId) AS VARCHAR(10)),3),DivId from Oper_Db.dbo.table1
```

if you want to start the sequence from 0, use this

```
insert into table2 (divdw_id,Divid)
 select RIGHT('000'+CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY DivId)-1 AS VARCHAR(10)),3),DivId from Oper_Db.dbo.table1
```

Comment: this is doing wrong,, when i execute this insert 5 values against 001 where as i want only 1 value i.e. 001 1 and when i execute with 002 then 002 2

Comment: Then, can you update the question with your exact requirement ? @seesharp

Comment: @seesharp I have Updated the answer

Comment: in select statement why there is divid then one which you write with cast ... because if divid series is 1,2,3,5,6 then divdw_id should be 1,2,3,4,5 against 1,2,3,5,6 ... whereas when i run your query this is inserting like this divdw_id (001,002,003,005,006) divid (001,002,003,005,006) where as i want divdwId (001,002,003,004,005) divid(001,002,003,005,006)

Comment: divdw_id will be a sequence number generated order by Divid and it does not have anything else with Divid.

Comment: YES thanku.. what if we start from 000 not from 001?

Comment: I have just added that option

Answer (score 0):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/insert-transact-sql

```
insert into table2 (divdw_id, divid)
 select RIGHT('000'+CAST(DivId as VARCHAR(3)),3),DivId from Oper_Db.dbo.table1
```

ps fortune-teller today on vacation, so we will guess your own desires

Comment: this is doing wrong,, when i execute this insert 5 values against 001 where as i want only 1 value i.e. 001 1 and when i execute with 002 then 002 2